# Why does the dtype of a numpy array automatically change to 'object' if you multiply the array with a number equal to or larger than 10**20?

Tags: python, numpy

Given an arbitrary `numpy` array (its size and shape don't seem to play a role)

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1.])
print(a.dtype)  # float64
```

it changes its `dtype` if you multiply it with a number equal or larger than `10**20`

```py
print((a*10**19).dtype)  # float64
print((a*10**20).dtype)  # object

a *= 10**20  # Throws TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' output (typecode 'O') 
#             could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'd') 
#             according to the casting rule ''same_kind''

a *= 10.**20  # Throws numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncOutputCastingError: 
#             Cannot cast ufunc 'multiply' output from dtype('float64') to 
#             dtype('int32') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

However, this doesn't happen if you multiply element-wise

```py
a[0] *= 10**20  
print(a, a.dtype)  # [1.e+20] float64
```

or specifically convert the number to a `float` (or `int`)

```py
a *= float(10**20)  
print(a, a.dtype)  # [1.e+20] float64
```

---

Just for the record, if you do the multiplication outside of `numpy`, there are no issues

```py
b = 1.
print(type(b), type(10**20), type(10.**20))  # float int float

b *= 10**20
print(type(b))  # float
```

Comment: `np.array(10**20)` produces `array(100000000000000000000, dtype=object)` becaue `10**20` too large for `int64`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect it is the size a "natural" integer can take on the system.

```
print(sys.maxsize, sys.getsizeof(sys.maxsize))
=> 9223372036854775807 36
print(10**19, sys.getsizeof(10**19))
=> 10000000000000000000 36
```

And this is where *on my system* the conversion to `object` starts, when I do

```
for i in range(1, 24):
    print(f'type of a*10**{i}:', (a * 10**i).dtype)
```

I do expect it is linked to the implementation of the integer:

> PEP 0237: Essentially, long renamed to int. That is, there is only one
> built-in integral type, named int; but it behaves mostly like the old
> long type.

See https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers

To notice this, one could use `numpy.multiply` with a forced output type. This will throw an error and not silently convert (similar to your `*=` example).

Comment: Thank you! But why is it then that this happens for multiplications with `numpy` arrays, but not for "regular" multiplications, or when multiplying element-wise?

Comment: I guess element wise and "regular" multiplication are the same? 
Python build-in types like `float`  and `int` (see [int.__mul__](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/026ee0057e2d/Objects/intobject.c#l525)) implement the Dunder methods `__mul__` and `__rmul__` in a different way than `ndarray` (see [ndarray.__mul__](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.__mul__.html))

Comment: I see, thanks! But what does `Return self*value.` even mean in this context? (Also, the comment "We check these two ways against each other, and declare victory if they're approximately the same." of the `int.__mul__` implementation is hilarious.)

Comment: Python `int` and `float` objects are implemented in C, thus `*` is the `*`-operator in C...